# Explain the Inequality: $a, b, c$ be positive real numbers such that $a + b + c = 3.$ Show that $a^b b^c c^a \le 1.$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, contest-math

> Let $a, b, c$ be positive real numbers such that $a + b + c = 3.$ Show that $a^b b^c c^a \le 1.$

[image]

Now, I understood how $\frac{ab+bc+ca}{a+b+c}\ge (a^bb^cc^a)^{\frac{1}{a+b+c}},$ but I couldn't understand why $ \frac{a+b+c}{3}\ge \frac{ab+bc+ca}{a+b+c}.$

Can anyone explain it? Any other solution is also appreciated.

Comment: More generally, see [Newton's inequalities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_inequalities).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$(a+b+c)^2=a^2+b^2+c^2+2(ab+bc+ca)~~~~(1)$$
By $a^2+b^2\ge 2ab$ etc we have
$$a^2+b^2+c^2\ge ab+bc+ca~~~~(2)$$
Add (1) and (2) to get
$$(a+b+c)^2 \ge 3(ab+bc+ca)$$
Now reshuffle this to get what you want.

Comment: yes! Thankyou! arrghh, IDK how I missed this!